# Moving Sitecore subdomain website to main website

Tags: multisite

I have multiple websites running on Single Sitecore instance. e.g.

http://xyz.com (**Main Website**) and http://abc.xyz.com (**another Sitecore website**)

Customer now wish to have only one site as below

http://xyz.com/abc/{pages from abc site}

Can we achieve this without disturbing current content structure in Sitecore. Just with some config changes?

Comment: You need to configure the second site as a virtual folder for the 1st site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378122/accessing-sitecore-content-with-virtual-folders

Comment: @ChrisAuer My Site structure is as below. 
C:\Sitecore\All Sites. Multiple sites in Single Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per commented by Chris, This is the correct answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378122/accessing-sitecore-content-with-virtual-folders

We need to mention physical folder same as virtual folder. Patch before attribute is very important here.

Add below attributes in our abc.xyz.com website settings

```
    <site name="abc.xyz.com" patch:before="site[@name='xyz.com']" 
    virtualFolder="/abc" physicalFolder="/abc"
    targetHostName="xyz.com" 

....
>
```

https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/virtualFolder.aspx